# Invoke fragment method from dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-dialog

Is there any way to invoke method in `MyDialog extends Dialog` from fragment that it creates? So I could use Context but don't know how.
The example is dialog that pick Open camera, gallery ect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an Interface in your Dialog for that purpose. You'll find an example at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html (you'll find the example under "Passing Events Back to the Dialog's Host").

Answer (score 0):

pretty easy, whenever opening the dialog use a TAG to mark it:

[DialogFragment.show(FragmentManager fm, String tag);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show(android.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String))

```
dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "MY_DIALOG");
```

then to retrieve it you call it:

```
MyDiagFrag diagFrag = (MyDiagFrag)getFragmentManager()
                                   .findFragmentByTag("MY_DIALOG")
```

Comment: Thanks, that is great and I really got that @Frank D. way is much better for me now.